# How we can use adfs services using web application?

Tags: windows-server-2012, adfs, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs3.0

I need help in authorization using ADFS claims, I have done with ADFS configuration on my windows server 2012 R2.

i have no idea what to do next.

My requirement is :
I have 2 sites which share resources I need if the user sign-in using one site then if he/she goes to the second site then the user needs to enter the credentials again but I want to skip this step

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure both applications as Relying Parties in ADFS.

Both applications need to have a client side stack supporting either WS-Fed (WIF) or SAML 2.0.

If you used ADFS 2016, you could also use OpenID Connect.

That gives you SSO across both applications.

Comment: What if my apps on the same server?

Comment: No difference - one app. = 1 RP.